# Updating SQL Server CE table returns an error in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm updating table based on other table column criteria.

What is the problem inside the following update query because I get this error:

[image]

The query I used is:

```
try
{
    StockDbConnection dbcon = new StockDbConnection();

    SqlCeConnection Conn = new SqlCeConnection(dbcon.ReturnConnection("ConnString"));
    Conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE a SET a.tPrice=(@Quantity) * (b.unitprice)"+
            "FROM SALES a"+
            "JOIN PRODUCT b ON a.pid=b.pid"+
            "WHERE a.pid=@prid", Conn);

    command.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", txtQty.Text);
    command.Parameters.Add("@prid", cmbPid.Text);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MessageBox.Show("Data is upated successfully.");
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
}
```

Note: There is relationship between table `PRODUCT` and `SALES` using `pid`

Comment: I suspect from the error that the tokens are case sensitive, have you tried `FROM` instead of `from`?

Comment: is there definitely a SALES table?

Comment: yes, I have SALES table definitely.

Answer (score 2):

I think problem on that like;

```
on a.pid = @prid
```

Here a syntax of Joins;

```
FROM first_table join_type second_table [ON (join_condition)]
```

And [from](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> *join_condition* defines the predicate to be evaluated for each pair of joined rows

I *strongly* suspect you should filter your `a.pid` column on `WHERE` clause, not `ON`.

Comment: Is it difficult to fix the problem?

Comment: I have voted up your answer and waiting to Accept it, steel need to fix the problem. Please can you edit my code and provide the fix.

Comment: @NurSelam your query is invalid. First try to create a working query using any version of SQL Server, then try to call the same query from code. Any version (including SQL Express) will tell you where the error is. If you simply changed `ON` to `WHERE` without removing the join, you still have an invalid query

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add Spaces in between Query Statements what you Concated

```
 SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("Update a set a.tPrice=(@Quantity) * (b.unitprice) " +
                " from SALES  a "+
                " join product b "+
                " on a.pid=@prid", Conn);
```

Comment: The join is still invalid

Comment: not work as your answer, Please can you help me by providing the Valid join.

Comment: Is it difficult to fix the problem?